# Spring MVC @RequestBody into an Interface instead of a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Folks,

This code snipped works:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Member>> findByMemberKeyOrUniqueMemberId(
```

Note that "Member" is an interface, not a class.

This does not work.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody final List<Member> members) {
```

So I can turn Members into JSON but I can't receive JSON into Members. If I change save's argument from List to a List of one of Member's classes then it works fine but it really messes up my code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Define _does not work_.

Comment: I get a 400 Bad Request if I try to deserialize into Members. I get a 200 OK and everything works if I use a Member class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jackson can not (it's infeasible) guess which `Member` implementation to use to deserialize the JSON.

Jackson offers `@JsonTypeInfo` as a way to describe your inheritance hierarchy and give it hints on how to deserialize JSON. However, this requires that you modify your JSON and add these hints. This is explained in the documentation, [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).

Comment: Just so I understand, it *can* determine which implementation to use to serialize to JSON but it can't determine which implementation to use to deserialize the JSON. Correct?

Comment: @techgnosis Right. For serializing, all it needs to do is call `getClass()` and build a serializer for that type. But there is (currently) no such type information when deserializing.