# Use interface in Spring controller method argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I've two classes `A` & `B` which are implementing an interface.

```
public class A implements MyInterface {

    // Class A stuff
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
 }
}

public class B implements MyInterface { 
    //Class B stuff

   private MyCustomClass myCustomclass;

   public String getName() {
    this.myCustomclass.getName();
 }
}


public interface MyInterface {

  public String getName();
}
```

I want to use a single controller method which can work on both A and B depending on which object the frontend sends. So when I try to use Interface, Spring complains no suitable message converter found.

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/mymethod", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
> public String updateRecord(@RequestBody MyInterface myInterface, HttpServletResponse response) { 
>         //Do stuff
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you add whole body of class A and B?

Comment: Added. Let me know if you've any doubts.

Comment: Are you using `jackson` for spring message mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jackson can determine which implementation is to use to serialize to JSON but it can't determine which to use to deserialize the JSON.  For serializing, all it needs to do is call getClass() and build a serializer for that type. But there is (currently) no such type information when deserializing. You should use the Jackson annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` to achieve polymorphic json.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "A"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B")})
public interface MyInterface {

}
```

Then the request body `myInterface` must be,

`{type:'A', name:'My name'}` or `{type:'B', myCustomclass:{....}}`

Refer these three :

[Spring MVC @RequestBody into an Interface instead of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056618/spring-mvc-requestbody-into-an-interface-instead-of-a-class)

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

[Spring @RequestBody containing a list of different types (but same interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247189/spring-requestbody-containing-a-list-of-different-types-but-same-interface)

Comment: for kotlin see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605575/how-to-use-jackson-jsonsubtypes-annotation-in-kotlin#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by passing Object class or by passing generic type reference?

```
public String updateRecord(@RequestBody Object obj,..
```

or

```
public String updateRecord(@RequestBody T obj,.. // I am not sure for this
```

Then check `instanceOf` in your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding spring/jackson will not be able to recognise what type of object to create unless incoming json explicitly mentions about the same. See below link, it talks about abstract classes though. Basically there are multiple ways to achieve this, using jsonTypeinfo or argument resolvers etc. Check if this helps. [Abstract classes and Spring MVC @ModelAttribute/@RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336920/abstract-classes-and-spring-mvc-modelattribute-requestparam)